# End of file exception while reading a file from remote hdfs cluster using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new to working with HDFS. I am trying to read a csv file which is stored in a hadoop cluster using spark. Every time i try to access it i get the following error:
 End of File Exception between local host

I have not setup hadoop locally since i already had access to hadoop cluster.

I may be missing some configurations but i dont know which ones. Would appreciate the help.

I tried to debug it using this :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949058/what-is-the-meaning-of-eof-exceptions-in-hadoop-namenode-connections-from-hbase)

Did not work for me.

This is the code using spark.

```
val conf= new SparkConf().setAppName("Read").setMaster("local").set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getName)
      .set("fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val data=sc.textfile("hdfs://<some-ip>/abc.csv)
```

I expect it to read the csv and convert it into RDD.

Getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is:

Comment: did you try this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478096/cannot-read-a-file-from-hdfs-using-spark

Comment: ya i have tried that. I am confused with where to set xml files if any needs to be added to configuration

Comment: @VaibhavSrivastava - if this cluster is personal you can try once format name node

Comment: I cannot do that since it is a shared cluster

Answer (score 0):

Run you spark jobs on hadoop cluster. Use below code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("Read").getOrCreate()
val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("<filePath>")
```

or you can use spark-shell as well.

If you want to access hdfs from your local, follow this:[link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Kerberos-Cross-Realm-HDFS-Access-Via-Spark-Application/m-p/201968)

Comment: I see the error comes when i try to perform action on the rdd returned. i am getting the error when i do data.count(). What could be the problem

Comment: @VaibhavSrivastava - this rdd's are lazy evolution so it is not perfomaining untill some action is triggred

Comment: ya so count() is an action right. When i try to perform count it is giving end of file error. How to resolve this